# How to retrieve Time in MySql Database using C# code

Tags: c#, mysql

How to access time value from MySQL Database table

```
DateTime tim = DateTime.Now.GetDateTimeFormats(mdr.GetDateTime("time"));
string s = tim.ToShortTimeString();
```

Comment: How is your database table storing the dates?
Also what did you try already achieving it?

Comment: Why are you calling `GetDateTimeFormats` at all? And why are you then calling `ToShortTimeString`? Isn't `mdr.GetDateTime("time")` all you need?

Answer (score 1):

So if the time is already saved in your table, you will be pulling the DateTime type in the form it exists in SQL. After you have that value you can manipulate it however you want via ToString("MM/dd/yy") or any other manipulation you want.

To pull the DateTime from the column "time" you would do as so, but also you might want to add a check to see if it is null first.

```
    mdr.GetDateTime(mdr.GetOrdinal("time");
```

You could combine both as a method like so...

```
    public static DateTime SafeGetDateTime(SqlDataReader reader, string colName)
    {
        if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal(colName)))
        {
            return reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal(colName));
        }

        return DateTime.MinValue;
    }
```

This would return the minimum possible value for DateTime if it is null, and its implementation would be while your DataReader reads and look like :

```
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);


            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader mdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (mdr.Read())
                {
                    string datetime = SafeGetDateTime(mdr, "time").ToShortTimeString();
                }
                conn.Close();
                return datetime;
             }
```

Comment: This isn't going to compile, and you may want to add some explanation and formatting to your answer.

Comment: Sorry, thank you for the advice.